# Dynamic word swapping animation 3

Tags: javascript, html

Following on from a previous question from 2011 titled Dynamic word swapping animation.

Thanks to Marek's answer I have been able to create an animation for text on a page that, every few seconds, changes one word out with another word from a list. However where previous question/ example was: "I have a header that says, "This is cool," but I want "cool" to be replaced every few seconds by "neat/awesome/groovy/etc".

I need my header to say eg, (for the sake of continuity) "This is cool man".  The problem I have is that because the alternate words are longer it makes the sentence vary in length as it rotates through each of the words.  Is there a way to specify, using Pure JS, for "man" to stay a set distance from "is", therefore the alternate words fill the gap between and the overall sentence remains the same length?

And, if the above is possible, can the alternate words be centred between "man" and "is"?

Any help greatly appreciated!  Phil

The Pure JS I currently have (from previous post mentioned) reads:

```
<script>
var words = ["neat", "great", "best", "groovy"];
var i = 0;
var text = "This is cool";
function _getChangedText() {
    i = (i + 1) % words.length;
    console.log(words[i]);
    return text.replace(/cool/, words[i]);
}
function _changeText() {
    var txt = _getChangedText();
    console.log(txt);
    $("#changer").text(txt);
}
setInterval("_changeText()", 1000);
</script>
<span id="changer">This is cool</span>
```

Comment: just a note - this is not 'pure', vanilla JS - jQuery is here, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more html/css thing... however, after few mods:

http://jsfiddle.net/X3wZV/1/

```
var words = ["neat", "great", "best", "groovy"];
var i = 0;
var text = "<span id='first'>This is</span> <span id='inner'>cool</span> <span id='sec'>man</span>";
function _getChangedText() {
    i = (i + 1) % words.length;
    console.log(words[i]);
    return text.replace(/cool/, words[i]);
}
function _changeText() {
    var txt = _getChangedText();
    console.log(txt);
    $("#changer").html(txt);
}
setInterval("_changeText()", 1000);
```

and a little styling (**check CSS, change it according to your needs**)...i think this is close to what you want, if i understand your question correctly... :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the 8th index of the string everytime and append man after the new word.

Is this what you mean?